# TableView doesnot populate data for the first time while tapping on Search bar

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I am trying to implement search bar through `UISearchController` and implemented the delegate as

```
 func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {

            filteredTableData.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

            let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text)

            let array = (tabledata as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
            filteredTableData = array as! [String]
            self.tblView.reloadData()

        }
```

However the `tableview` doesn't get populate with data when we tap on the search bar. Otherwise it works all fine.

I also tried checking the text of search bar >1 or not, but it works at the initial but gives me error on backspace. What is the hack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should implement [UISearchbarDelegate's](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/index.html) this method

- searchBar:textDidChange:

so your line will be

```
 func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) 
{

        filteredTableData.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
        let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchBar.text)

        let array = (tabledata as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
        filteredTableData = array as! [String]
        self.tblView.reloadData()
}
```

You need to set searchBar.delegate to self before this

Comment: umm..i though there might be some hack out there in the above delegate..thanks man

Comment: thanks for your idea...although it didnot work..need to do a liitle work on that..so i am posting your idea as an answer

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem is as

func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {

```
if count(searchController.searchBar.text) > 0{


    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text)

    let array = (tabledata as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
    filteredTableData = array as! [String]
    self.tblView.reloadData()
}else if count(searchController.searchBar.text) == 0 {

    filteredTableData =  tabledata
    self.tblView.reloadData()

}
```

you can either do as Saad idea as :

```
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {


    if count(searchBar.text) > 0{


    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchBar.text)

    let array = (tabledata as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
    filteredTableData = array as! [String]
    self.tblView.reloadData()
    }else if count(searchBar.text) == 0 {

          filteredTableData =  tabledata
        self.tblView.reloadData()

    }


}
```